# Intuition behind this strange heuristic for primitive roots modulo $p$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, primitive-roots

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Define $S(p)$ as the sum of all primitive roots modulo $p$ taken from $\left[-\frac{p-1}2,\frac{p-1}2\right]$.

Now here's the strange thing. If the primitive roots were 'random', you'd expect $S(p)$ to be negative about as often as it is positive. However, experiments suggest that, at the very least,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\#\{p\le n:S(p)<0\}}{\#\{p\le n:S(p)>0\}}>2.$$
This is **extremely counter-intuitive** to me.

I don't expect one can compute the limit, or even prove it exists. But is there some intuition behind this phenomenon?

**EDIT:** If $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, it is easy to see $S(p)=0$. Now consider $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$. We can go further and split into cases mod $8$. I've computed $S(p)$ for all primes $p<10^5$ with $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

The value of $p$ modulo $8$ turns out to matter a whole lot. For $p\equiv 3\pmod 8$, I found
$$
\begin{align*}
\#\{p\le 10^5:p\equiv 3\pmod 8,S(p)>0\}&=204;\\
\#\{p\le 10^5:p\equiv 3\pmod 8,S(p)=0\}&=10;\\
\#\{p\le 10^5:p\equiv 3\pmod 8,S(p)<0\}&=2196.
\end{align*}
$$
Meanwhile, the behavior for $p\equiv 7\pmod 8$ is completely different:
$$
\begin{align*}
\#\{p\le 10^5:p\equiv 7\pmod 8,S(p)>0\}&=1278;\\
\#\{p\le 10^5:p\equiv 7\pmod 8,S(p)=0\}&=39;\\
\#\{p\le 10^5:p\equiv 7\pmod 8,S(p)<0\}&=1083.
\end{align*}
$$
Refining even further: up to $10^5$ there are $1203$ primes $p$ satisfying $p\equiv 11\pmod {24}$. With the *sole exception* of the prime $65171$, these primes satisfy $S(p)<0$.

Comment: It is known that when $p\equiv3\pmod4$, there are more quadratic nonresidues in $[-\frac p2,0]$ than there are in $[0,\frac p2]$ ([this question's answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25263/most-squares-in-the-first-half-interval) give entry points into the literature). Being a quadratic nonresidue is necessary for being a primitive root, so I suspect the two phenomena are connected.

Comment: If $a$ is a primitive root $-a$ isn't

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee That’s false unless you assume $p=4k+3$.  For instance, the primitive roots of $5$ are $2$ and $-2$, so it’s completely backwards for this case.

Comment: Well $a^n$ and $(-a)^n$ are additive inverses( doh if $n$ is odd), so where $-1$ shows up in one $1$ shows up for the other.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Yep, you spotted the problem with your logic.  When the modulus is $1$ mod $4$ the order of the multiplicative group is divisible by $4$, so the value of $n$ for which $a^n = -1$ is even.

Comment: My answer here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388722/distribution-of-primitive-elements-finite-fields-prime-order/4683979#4683979 shows that $S(p)$ is approximately $0$ with an error term of size at most $O(p^{29/15})$. Of course, the size of the error can go down if we are more careful. However, this result does not give any information toward the sign bias.